# How to export dependencies whole?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, transitive-dependency

I have a library `B` that depends on another library `A`.
A third library `C` depends on `B` and `A`.
I can satisfy `C`'s dependencies with

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('/path/A.jar')
    implementation files('/path/B.jar')
}
```

but I would rather only declare `B` and build `B.jar` in such a way that it contains and exposes `A` as well.
I know that with `api files('/path/A.jar')` `B` can expose the parts of `A` that it uses in interfaces, but (my experience is that) it doesn't let consuming projects import anything from `A` explicitly.
How can `B` expose `A` completely?

Answer (score 1):

files() is only for local flat file use, there are 2 mechanisms to share transitive dependencies ...

```
project(':other')        (project dependency) 
'group:artifact:version' (maven repository dependency)
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-types

if the source for B & A is available locally & can be built along with C ... then declaring like below is possible

```
implementation project(':A')
implementation project(':B')
```

else you go with proper maven repository artefact.